# Prove if $E[Y|\mathcal{G}] = X$ and $E[Y^2|\mathcal{G}] = X^2$ then $X=Y$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

This is the complete problem:

Let be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ probability space.
$\mathcal{G}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. X and Y are random variables with Y square integrable.

Prove if $E[Y|\mathcal{G}] = X$ and $E[Y^2|\mathcal{G}] = X^2$ then $X=Y$ almost surely.

This is what I tried:

if $E[Y|G]=X$ and $E[Y^2|G]=X^2 \implies \forall A \in \mathcal{G}$:
$$ \int_A E[Y|G] dP = \int_A X dP$$
$$ \int_A E[Y^2|G] dP = \int_A X^2 dP$$

This is the same as:
$$ \int_{w \in A} E[Y|G] dP = \int_{w \in A} X dP = \int_{w \in A} Y dP$$
$$ \int_{w \in A} E[Y^2|G] dP = \int_{w \in A} X^2 dP = \int_{w \in A} Y^2 dP$$

$$\int_{w \in A} X dP = X(A).P(A) = Y(A).P(A)$$
it follows that: $X=Y$ almost surely.

I don't know why I need the equality $\int_{w \in A} E[Y^2|G] dP = \int_{w \in A} X^2 dP$, if I'm missing some steps or if what I've tried is simply plain wrong.

**Edit:** for the Completeness:

My mistake was in the last step, the equality 
$$\int_{w \in A} X dP = X(A).P(A)$$ 
holds when $X$ is constant on the $A$ set. Not for every random variable $X$.

Comment: What do you call X(A) and Y(A) exactly (last line before "it follows")?

Comment: @Did , $X(A) = r1 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Y(A) = r2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, so $X^{-1}(r1)\in A$ and $Y^{-1}(r1)\in A$

Comment: Sorry but I have absolutely no idea of what you are talking about. This does not seem to belong to probability theory in the usual sense of the term.

Comment: @Did it is a mix of probability and measure theory

Comment: See previous comment. It seems that **you** have no idea of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E(Y\mid \mathcal{G}) = X$, then $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Then
\begin{align*}
E\Big((X-Y)^2\mid \mathcal{G}\Big) &= E\Big(\big(X^2+Y^2-2XY\big)\mid \mathcal{G}\Big)\\
&= X^2 + X^2 - 2X X = 0,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E\Big((X-Y)^2\Big) &= E\bigg( E\Big((X-Y)^2\mid \mathcal{G}\Big)\bigg)\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
That is, $X=Y$ almost surely.

Comment: I got it clear when reading this http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1119209/154124